# How to keep images from wrapping?

Tags: css, image, css-float, word-wrap

I need to keep a group of images from wrapping.

I was hoping the css below would do it, but it's still not working.

```
img {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: none;
}
```

Here's the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BwM8SuOpV49MuxXSnfP6?p=preview

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

Here's a better example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WwIh6EoHcpHO18Ln06Td?p=preview

This shows a sentence (with each character rendered as an image) being wrapped at the wrong spot. Is it possible to set a css nowrap value per image?

Answer (score 0):

...ok, figured it out: the solution is to wrap each word in an inline-block span

Answer (score -1):

CSS clear property

---

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

---

```
clear: none|left|right|both|initial|inherit;
```